# How to get http or https from the url which is placed in page

Tags: java, http, https

I have an application which is migrating to new version. Old URL contains HTTP protocol while new URL contains HTTPS protocol. When the user clicks on the URL in the web page, I have a java code where I have some checks to be done for authentication and will redirect to application URL post authentication. When I hard code the URL to HTTPS it is working fine.

I tried using `request.getScheme();`. It is working for HTTP URL but not for HTTPS.
I need both URLs to work. Can some one please help me how to get HTTP or HTTPS from URL.

Comment: I suppose it's JEE ? what server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use getProtocol() method of URL class. For Example,

```
URL url = new URL("<your URL>");
System.out.println(url.getProtocol());
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi, I need to get url. So i can not pass the url value directly.

Comment: When url is hit by user, we get request.getParameter("host"); hostname, similarly port and remaining. How do we get the protocol

Comment: There are couple of way to know the protocol of the request.
1. Use HttpSerlvetRequest.isSecure().
2. Use request.getScheme() to know whether request using http or https

Comment: Here's the scenario.

My Java web application has following path
https://www.mywebsite.com:9443/MyWebApp
Let's say there is a JSP file
https://www.mywebsite.com:9443/MyWebApp/protected/index.jsp
and I need to retrieve 
https://www.mywebsite.com:9443/MyWebApp 
 within this JSP file.
I need to get http or https request first in JSP page and i need to pass to servelet and depending  on htpp and https i need to redirect user to different pages.